# REST url param naming convention

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, url-parameters

I have a REST call to search students

> /students?name=&no=

name and no are optional.

I am searching students with name contains. i.e. if I send name="sh" then it will return all students which name **contains** "sh".

AND

for no, it is no starts with ie if no=10 then it will return all students with no **starts with** 10

What are **standard** naming convention for such parameters.
Can I say

> /students?nameContains=&noStartsWith=

OR

> /students?name=&no=

Which one is correct way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist no standard naming conventions for query parameters. In your specific case, it depends on the likelihood of future requirements. If it's just `nameContains`, well, that's much better than `name`. But if you're going to need `nameContains`, `nameStartsWith`, `nameEndsWith`, etc., that's going to get messy fast. Then you should consider either a separate resource that specifies search criteria or adding wildcards to your `name`, such as:

```
?name=Bob*  <!-- name starts with Bob -->
?name=*h   <!-- name ends with h -->
?name=Sa?  <!-- name has three letters and starts 'Sa' -->
```

For truly complex cases, you need to think about either supporting regexes or using an existing library to handle search. Also think about if you need to support `?nameIgnoreCase`, which would argue strongly in favor of wildcards rather than multiple query parameters.

Comment: By REST using RDF it is possible to use triple fragments and URI templates in a combination: http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/triple-pattern-fragments/ , but this is just a draft. Another option to use a SPARQL endpoint for querying. You are right that there are no standard solutions for general querying through HTTP. We need a standard query descriptor vocab by RDF, or a new standard query language for URI queries by non-RDF. By simple queries URI templates can help.